# How to avoid citations being placed on a new line when \blockcquote ends with a list?

Tags: biblatex, lists, line-breaking, quoting, csquotes

When [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)'s `\blockquote` and `displaycquote` ends with a list the citation is put on the next line after the list rather than directly after the last list item. Can one force `csquotes` to place the citation directly after the last list item?

The following is an example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@book{texbook,
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  title     = {The {{\TeX}book}},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  date      = {1984}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{database.bib}

\begin{document}

% Bad placement of citation
\blockcquote{texbook}{%
  Some cited text:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \end{itemize}%
}

% Bad placement of citation
\begin{displaycquote}{texbook}
  Some cited text:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{displaycquote}

% Correct placement of citation
\begin{quote}
  Some cited text:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2 \cite{texbook}
  \end{itemize}
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

The following is the output of the example. Note how the first and second citations are badly placed while the third one is correctly placed.

[image: Output of example]

Comment: The problem is actually more general. I have the same situation when I use `csquotes`' `\MakeBlockQuote` function and try to add a footnote.

Comment: You're telling to end an `itemize` environment, what else are you expecting? An `\end{itemize}` *always* ends a paragraph.

Comment: @egreg If I end `itemize` after `\blockcquote` or `displaycquote` I get an error. I would simply like to typeset quotations with `\blockcquote` and `displaycquote`, even those that end with the last list item.

Comment: @N.N. Then you need to insert the quotation or citation *before* the `itemize` ends.

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to that and still use `\blockcquote` or `displaycquote`?

Comment: @N.N. It's quite hard to understand what you want: just write `...\cite{textbook}\end{blockquote}`.

Comment: @egreg If `\blockcquote` or `displaycquote` ends with an `\end{itemize}` I want the citation to be placed before `\end{itemize}` (rather than after it).

Comment: Quite a tough problem. I believe that a `\citehere` command similar to `\qedhere` of `amsthm` could be a good way to solve the problem, but this probably requires rewriting many parts of `csquotes`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can locally make `itemize` (and other display list environments) look ahead and see if they are at the end of the quote construct, and if so, do the cite and locally disable the cite command so that it does nothing when the `csquotes` command executes `\cite` after the display.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@book{texbook,
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  title     = {The {{\TeX}book}},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  date      = {1984}
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatletter
\let\oldbcq\blockcquote
\let\oldendlist\endlist
\def\csq@@z{\csq@z{\csq@z}}
\def\csq@@@z{\end{displaycquote}}
\long\def\cqendlist#1\fi#2\fi#3#4{%
\def\z{#3{#4}}%
\ifx\z\csq@@@z\let\z\csq@@z\fi
\ifx\z\csq@@z
\ifhmode\unskip\fi
\leavevmode
\space \zcsqcite
\gdef\cs@next{\let\csq@cite\@gobble}%
\else
\global\let\cs@next\relax
\fi
\oldendlist#1\fi#2\fi#3{#4}%
\cs@next
}
\enditemize
\let\csq@z\relax
\def\blockcquote#1#2{\begingroup
\def\zcsqcite{\csq@cite{#1}}%
\let\enditemize\cqendlist
\oldbcq{#1}{#2\csq@z\csq@z}\endgroup}

\let\olddcq\displaycquote
\def\displaycquote#1{%
\def\zcsqcite{\csq@cite{#1}}%
\let\enditemize\cqendlist
\olddcq{#1}}

\let\oldedcq\enddisplaycquote
\def\enddisplaycquote{%
\cs@next
\oldedcq}

\makeatother
\bibliography{database.bib}

\begin{document}



% Bad placement of citation
\blockcquote{texbook}{%
  Some cited text:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \end{itemize}}%


%\tracingall
% Bad placement of citation
\begin{displaycquote}{texbook}
  Some cited text:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{displaycquote}

% Correct placement of citation
\begin{quote}
  Some cited text:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2 \cite{texbook}
  \end{itemize}
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me. I get several "Undefined control sequence" and "Missing number, treated as zero" errors. Is there any way to post an MWE in the comment?!

Comment: @Grodon no but you can edit (or propose an edit depending on rep) my answer, I just ran the above again just now and got no error from pdflatex, unfortunately though I can't run biber (operating system issues, yet to be resolved, needs a newer perl than cygwin has) so can't test latex after biber has run

Comment: @Grodon easier might be if you just go to the chatroom http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends and post the error log there

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, and here's how I've solved it :

**The problem :**

I had defined personal quoting commands combined to the citation, making the same things as the **\blockquote** or **\displaycquote** :

```
\newcommand{\kb}[3]{\begin{quote} \begin{singlespace} \smaller \og {\itshape  #3} \fg \nolinebreak
\cite[#1]{#2} \end{singlespace} \end{quote}}
```

But when it was ending with an **itemize** environment, I was having the same problem as you : the **\cite** informations were on a new line.

**My solution :**

I've chosen to split the command into two pieces :

- a quoting command **without** the citation reference (\kd)
- on the **last \item** line, the text with the reference (\kf)

So we have :

```
\newcommand{\kd}[1]{\begin{quote} \begin{singlespace} \smaller \og {\itshape  #1} \end{singlespace} \end{quote}}
\newcommand{\kf}[3]{#3 \emph{\fg (\cite[#1]{#2})}}
```

So, in my document, I'm writing the things in this way :

```
\kd{Les hirondelles
\begin{itemize}
\item bonjour bonjour
\item les hirondelles
\item \kf{200}{BROUDIC1995}{ya d'la joie}
\end{itemize}
}
```

And it works. Graphically, at least, because I suppose that the program understands that it's only "ya d'la joie", which is related to the reference, while in fact it's the whole text. Anyway, it shows the right thing.