# No new line after environments in block quotes for citation and quotation marks

Tags: citing, line-breaking, itemize, enumitem, csquotes

My question is heavily related to this one: [How to avoid citations being placed on a new line when \blockcquote ends with a list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55302/how-to-avoid-citations-being-placed-on-a-new-line-when-blockcquote-ends-with-a)

I manged to adapt the solution proposed in the aforementioned question to my thesis.
I removed all `blockquote` related parts and added an `enit@` prefix to list related commands to cope with `enumitem`'s changes.
Also, I changed the redefiniton of `displaycquote` such that it takes optional arguments into account.
(Exact code can be found below.)

However, the style guide for my thesis requires me to put quotation marks around block quotes.
I need to extend the solution linked above such that it also places the closing quotation marks at the end of the `itemize` block.

Originally, in order to wrap `displaycquote` in quotation marks, I went with the renewing `\mkbegdispquote` and `\mkenddispquote`:

```
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\openautoquote}
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{\closeautoquote#1#2}
```

However, this does not work as the output looks like this:

[image]

Another problem I have is that blockquotes without `itemize` at the end don't get any citation.

Here is my current working version:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{texbook,
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  title     = {The {{\TeX}book}},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  date      = {1984}
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\makeatletter

\let\oldendlist\enit@endlist
\def\csq@@z{\csq@z{\csq@z}}
\def\csq@@@z{\end{displaycquote}}
\long\def\cqendlist#1\fi#2\fi#3#4{%
    \def\z{#3{#4}}%
    \ifx\z\csq@@@z\let\z\csq@@z\fi
        \ifx\z\csq@@z
        \ifhmode\unskip\fi
        \leavevmode
        \space \zcsqcite
        \gdef\cs@next{\let\csq@cite\@gobble}%
    \else
        \global\let\cs@next\relax
    \fi
    \oldendlist#1\fi#2\fi#3{#4}%
    \cs@next
}

\let\olddcq\displaycquote
\renewcommand\displaycquote[2][]{%
    \def\zcsqcite{\csq@cite[#1]{#2}}%
    \let\enit@enditemize\cqendlist
    \olddcq{#1}}

\let\oldedcq\enddisplaycquote
\def\enddisplaycquote{%
    \cs@next
    \oldedcq}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{displaycquote}[pp.88:2-3]{texbook}
  This is a list:
  \begin{itemize}
      \item with
      \item bullet
      \item points
  \end{itemize}
\end{displaycquote}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can remove biblatex and filecontents and still get the error.  However if you remove `enumitem` the error goes, it appears my code that you copied from the example is assuming a standard `itemize` not an enumitem version. Probably fixable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue.
The main problem was that `\openautoquote` and `\closeautoquote` must not be placed at different levels of environments, i.e. having one in the `displaycquote` environment itself and one in the nested `itemize` environment will break the code.
I now opted to change `\mkenddispquote` instead of `\cqs@cite`.
This code works for me now:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{texbook,
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  title     = {The {{\TeX}book}},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  date      = {1984}
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

% Use quotation marks in block quotes
\renewcommand\mkbegdispquote[2]{``}
\renewcommand\mkenddispquote[2]{''#1#2}

\makeatletter

\let\oldendlist\enit@endlist
\def\csq@@z{\csq@z{\csq@z}}
\def\csq@@@z{\end{displaycquote}}
\long\def\cqendlist#1\fi#2\fi#3#4{%
    \def\z{#3{#4}}%
    \ifx \z \csq@@@z
        \let\z\csq@@z
    \fi
    \ifx \z \csq@@z
        \ifhmode
            \unskip
        \fi
        \leavevmode
        '' \zcsqcite
        \gdef\cs@next{\let\mkenddispquote\@gobbletwo}%
    \fi
    \oldendlist#1\fi#2\fi#3{#4}%
}

\let\olddcq\displaycquote
\renewcommand\displaycquote[2][]{%
    \let\cs@next\relax
    \def\zcsqcite{\csq@cite[#1]{#2}}%
    \let\enit@enditemize\cqendlist
    \olddcq[#1]{#2}}

\let\oldedcq\enddisplaycquote
\def\enddisplaycquote{%
    \cs@next
    \oldedcq}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{displaycquote}[pp.88:2-3]{texbook}
    Quote without block.
\end{displaycquote}

\begin{displaycquote}[pp.88:2-3]{texbook}
    This is a list:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item with
        \item bullet
        \item points
    \end{itemize}
\end{displaycquote}

\begin{displaycquote}[pp.88:2-3]{texbook}
    Quote without block.
\end{displaycquote}

\textcquote[p.88:2]{texbook}{Let's check that other csquotes commands still work}

\end{document}
```